# UIImageView image not retained during drawRect event in iOS7

Tags: ios, properties, uiimageview, transparency, drawrect

I am transitioning an app project from iOS-6.1 and xcode4 to iOS-7 and xcode5. My original iOS-6.1 routine to draw on a transparent UIView above an UIImageView does not work in iOS7. Here is what I have done and how I have fixed it. I'm hoping someone can tell me how to do it better!

Using InterfaceBuilder, I create a square (320 x 320) UIImageView on my View Controller view. I then make a 320 x 320 UIView directly above it and use Interface Builder Attributes Inspector to make it transparent.

Then I link up the setters and getters in Interface Builder. The UIImageView @property is (nonatomic, retain). I then subclass the now-transparent UIView and do my drawing in drawRect.

In iOS6.1 this works just fine. In iOS-7 I have a problem.

(Several, actually). As a side note, in xcode5 I cannot get the Attributes Inspector to appear when I select the UIView, when I try to make the UIView transparent. Could this be a bug, perhaps in my installation of xcode5, or is the xcode5 Attributes Inspector no longer supporting UIViews?

So I make the UIView transparent programmatically in iOS-7. I'm doing it here in the UIView's drawRect, which is probably overkill, but I'm still trying to figure out what's going on:

```
 self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 self.opaque= NO;
 self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```

and then I have to make the UIImageView appear, also in drawRect, using this code

```
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage.png"];
CGRect imageRect;
imageRect.origin.x = self.bounds.origin.x + 10;
imageRect.origin.y = self.bounds.origin.y + 10;
imageRect.size.width = 300;
imageRect.size.height = 300;
[myImage drawInRect:imageRect];
```

And things are now fine. I get what I want which is my drawing on top of the image. But, it seems like a terrible performance hit to be calling myImage every time drawRect needs to be called.

Can anybody see why my original method of displaying the UIImageView once does not work in iOS-7? Has anybody a better solution to my expensive show-the-image-every-time method?

Thanks in advance

TFR